# javascript not running on textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My JavaScript seems not to be running

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
   function snip(len) {
      return function (e) {e.target.value = e.target.value.slice(0, len);};
   }

  function prevent(len) {
     return function () {
        if (e.target.value.length >= len) {
           e.preventDefault();
           return false;
        }
    }
 }

  var len = 13;

  var textarea = document.getElementById('text1'),
  sn = snip(len),
  p1 = prevent(len), p2 = snip(len - 12);

  textarea.addEventListener('change' ,p2 ,true);
  textarea.addEventListener('input' , sn ,true);
  textarea.addEventListener('keypress', p2,true);
  textarea.addEventListener('paste' ,p2 ,true);


 )};
 </script>
```

In my html mark-up I have a `<textarea>` element with an `id` of `text1`.

How can I change my js to operate on the textarea?

Comment: have you tried using $(document).onload instead of $(document).ready?

Comment: Did you include the `jQuery` library? You need to import it in order to use some of the code you've shown. You can download it here: [http://jquery.com/download/](http://jquery.com/download/)

Comment: thanks for the reply but I got it an hour ago thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the jquery library in your page?

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You are using jquery code as follows which will require the jquery library to be included:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the error console, you would find out that your parentheses at the end are switched around; the code should end in `});` but ends in `)};`. Also, your HTML does not show jQuery being included, but you use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
 function snip(len) {
        return function (e) {e.target.value = e.target.value.slice(0, len);};
    }
    function prevent(len) {
        return function () {
            if (e.target.value.length >= len) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
$(function(){
      var len = 13;
      var textarea = document.getElementById('text1'),
      sn = snip(len),
       p1 = prevent(len), p2 = snip(len - 12);

      textarea.addEventListener('change' ,p2 ,true);
      textarea.addEventListener('input' , sn ,true);
      textarea.addEventListener('keypress', p2,true);
      textarea.addEventListener('paste' ,p2 ,true);
 )};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to do.

First, include jQuery before your script.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

And you should end with `});`. Try the working code below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    function snip(len) {
        return function (e) {e.target.value = e.target.value.slice(0, len);};
    }
    function prevent(len) {
        return function () {
            if (e.target.value.length >= len) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    var len = 13;

    var textarea = document.getElementById('text1'),
    sn = snip(len),
    p1 = prevent(len), p2 = snip(len - 12);

    textarea.addEventListener('change' ,p2 ,true);
    textarea.addEventListener('input' , sn ,true);
    textarea.addEventListener('keypress', p2,true);
    textarea.addEventListener('paste' ,p2 ,true);
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <textarea id="text1" maxlength="99"></textarea>
</body> 
</html>
```